# Show Table View Cell when WebView is loaded

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in my Grouped Table View, and because the heightfor one cell is variable I want the function heightForRowAtIndexPath to wait for the webViewDidFinish befor it is calculated. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried, but what if you do [_myTable reloadData]; at the end of your webViewDidFinish?  That should reload the table information.

Or you could try a BOOL with a while loop?

Set the boolStillLoading to true before sending the request, then when it comes back then set it to false

```
viewDidLoad...
while(boolStillLoading){
    sleep(.2);
}
```

It's not pretty or probably the most efficient way, but it will keep the table from loading while you execute stuff before it.

Would love to see other approaches though...

Comment: Hm, the first thing did nothing and by the second it doesnt load the whole view...

Answer (score 0):

You cant stop calling heightForRowAtIndexPath explicitly, but you can make a tweak for this. after loadingweb view again call table reload data for height.

Use Web view delegate method for the same.

```
– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:

– webViewDidStartLoad:

– webViewDidFinishLoad:

– webView:didFailLoadWithError:
```

store variable value (for hieght) in webViewDidFinishLoad and then call tableview reload data. now in cellForRowAtIndex method use this variable for height.